# Is there a way to declare a 2 dimensional array of List in a type safe manner in Java?

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array, type-safety

Here is the code I have that works but with a type safety warning when I size and instantiate the array:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    private static final int MAX_ROWS = 2;
    private static final int MAX_COLS = 5;
    
    private List<String> _stringSets[][];
    
    public Test() {
        _stringSets = new List[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
        
        for(int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < MAX_COLS; col++) {
                _stringSets[row][col] = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried

```
_stringSets = new List<String>[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
```

but this won't work...

Comment: You are mixing arrays and Lists, these are 2 different things

Answer (score 0):

Lists are unidimensional and would be declared something like this:

`List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>()`

When you seem to be looking for a 2-dimensional arrays, which are declared something like this:

`String[][] myArray = new String[n1][n2]`

So what you want is probably something along those lines:

```
public class Test {

    private static final int MAX_ROWS = 2;
    private static final int MAX_COLS = 5;

    private String[][] stringSets;

    public Test() {
        stringSets = new String[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];

        for(int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < MAX_COLS; col++) {
                stringSets[row][col] = row+"-"+col;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally not recommended to mix Arrays and Lists in this way. May want to consider using other data structures to achieve a similar effect instead. For example, you could create a Map that uses Position coordinates to achieve similar results.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MapList {

  private static Map<Position, List<Integer>> mapList;
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int MAX_X = 5;
    final int MAX_Y = 6;
    
    mapList = new HashMap<>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_X; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < MAX_Y; j++) {
        mapList.put(new Position(i, j), new ArrayList<>());
        for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
          mapList.get(new Position(i, j)).add(k);
        }
      }
    }
    
    for(Position p : mapList.keySet())
      System.out.println(p.toString() + mapList.get(p));
  }
  
  private static class Position {
    private Integer x;
    private Integer y;
    
    public Position(Integer x, Integer y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if(this == o)
        return true;
      if(o == null)
        return false;
      if(getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;
      Position other = (Position) o;
      return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "(x:" + x + ", y:" + y + ")";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be over engineered for what I am trying to do. It is the same reason why I am not using lists of lists. It's ugly.  My solution is simple to grasp but not type safe. At any rate, I wasn't looking for a debate on the merits of mixing arrays with lists...That was NOT the question -- I simply missed the explanation from Oracle and after looking further I found it. If that makes me lazy so be it.

Comment: @Lauren_G You're working with a complicated data structure (collections inside collections inside collections). I would not consider it over engineering to flatten your interactions to just collections inside another collection, but that's just my thoughts. Mixing a fixed sized collection like an Array with a dynamic structure like a List may not be the focus of the question, but it's still worth mentioning given the problems such a relationship can create.

Comment: It is NOT a complex data structure. It's just a table with rows and columns :) Think of it this way...I have a spreadsheet with rows and columns with each cell being a List. I need a quick and dirty way of getting a list through indexing.  I suppose I could have created a Table class with a get function where i specify the row and column to return a List but as I explained to you before -- why over engineer a solution when a 2 dimensional array models the same thing for free. Generics has it place, but there are situations where it also gets in the way of simplicity.

Comment: @Lauren_G Definitely won't hear me arguing against your comment regarding generics. That tool is definitely a double edged one. I'll kindly agree to disagree regarding the complexity of working with nested collections like that though, at least in regards to working with it raw without supporting functionality to simplify navigating it (have a personal compulsion to mask anything more complex than a 2D matrix interaction behind methods and other classes when possible).